# How to unsquash a commit?

Tags: git

I have squashed 40 commmits at some point in time, and would like to pick back one commit. Is there some way to do this? I have the commit ref (93ebc467ff512580ae3c5a76790f09dfd5e3e6f2) that I would like to unsquash.

Comment: More information may help. What do you mean by 'unsquash` and 'pick back'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add the patch representing that commit onto the top of the branch you are on by doing

```
git cherry-pick 93ebc467ff512580ae3c5a76790f09dfd5e3e6f2
```

Answer (score 15):

You could use `git reflog` to browse all the commits that existed! Or since you have the commit hash you could just do a `git checkout 93ebc467ff512580ae3c5a76790f09dfd5e3e6f2` and see the commit itself..

Answer (score 5):

run this command on the terminal, which will give you list of squash commits

```
git reflog
```

[image]

then you can checkout to any commit by using commit hash like this

```
git checkout 953a9b5
```